# How is Map.Entry really declared?

Tags: java

[Documentation for Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) states in the beginning:

> public static interface Map.Entry<K,V>

But if I look at [the source file Map.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Map.java) in the OpenJDK repository, the Map interface seems to declare Entry simply as:

> interface Entry<K, V>

I am confused about why the modifiers "public static" are missing. How does Map.Entry become a public static member of Map if the actual source code omits these modifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `public` and `static` modifiers are implicit in the source code, because the `Entry` interface is a member of the `Map` interface. See the JLS sections:

[§6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> All members of interfaces lacking access modifiers are implicitly public.

[§9.1.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.3)

> A nested interface is implicitly static. That is, every member interface and local interface is static. It is permitted for the declaration of a member interface to redundantly specify the static modifier (§9.5), but it is not permitted for the declaration of a local interface (§14.3).

It is perfectly fine (produces no errors) for you to add `public static` to the interface declaration.

After all, the purpose of documentation is to *inform* people, not to reflect what is in the source code 100% accurately. Rather than having readers figure out what modifiers the interface implicitly has by going to the JLS, it conveniently states it in the first line after the header.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I had tried to find an answer from JLS but could not locate the right part...